# Relationships on Cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, model, foreign-keys, cakephp-2.0, relationship

I have two models : `Absence, Students`;

Absence fetch name and absence number from Students, now i want to linking model together, but i have been struggling to figure out how to map those relationships,

i dont have groups table, cause works well before, but now cake php said error by not have linking model., i used this following line before and work fine!

```
    $this->loadModel("Student");
    $siswas=$this->Student->find('all');
    $this->set('students', $siswas);
```

but now i have error detected, named Internal server 500, and i don't know what i have to do.,
before my application is fine, but now is something wrong happens, now i need to linking model together, i need help for it..

any help would appreciated..

**EDIT :**

"My Problems has been Solved, the problem is because database is not working well thank for the answers"

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error logs for what is causing the 500 error?

Comment: php error logs said
`2012-08-01 15:11:45 Warning: Warning (2): explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in [/home/magang/public_html/smkn1pst/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php, line 2236]
Trace:
explode - [internal], line ??
FormHelper::setEntity() - CORE/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php, line 2236
FormHelper::error() - CORE/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php, line 658
FormHelper::input() - CORE/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php, line 1100`

Comment: and `include - APP/View/Layouts/default.ctp, line 431
View::_render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 598
View::renderLayout() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 414
View::render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 376
Controller::render() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 898
ExceptionRenderer::_outputMessage() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 267
ExceptionRenderer::error500() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 234
ExceptionRenderer::render() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 170`

Comment: and `ErrorHandler::handleException() - CORE/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php, line 127
[main] - [internal], line ??`

Comment: Next time just add the code into your original question :) Does the script work if you remove those lines you added in your question?

Comment: if i'm remove `$siswas=$this->Student->find('all');` the error on the AbsenceController, the internal server 500 is gone, but still doesn't work too..

Comment: @anonymousyoung, I believe mistake could be in your View file. According you set method format in View it should look like `$student['Student']['name']`, not `$student['name']`. Make double check if you don't make mistake on View.

Comment: @xeranas i do this to my form elements `<td><?echo $this->Form->label("students_id",$oh['Student']['nama_siswa']);?></td>`

Comment: @anonymousyoung, still if `$siswas = ClassRegistry::init('Student')->find('all');` won't help you either then it means your problem is not in model relationships. Try play with `debug($this);exit();` in your code, maybe you find clue.

Comment: My Problems has been Solved, the problem is because database is not working well , thank @xeranas for the answers

Answer (score 1):

Table structure would be :

```
Students Table
id    student_name   other fields

absents table
id  student_id  other fields
```

student Model realationship

```
$hasMany = array('Absent');
```

Absent Model realationship

```
$belongsTo = array('Student');
```

Comment: i do well with your following method 
i use this to my Absence model `public $useTable ="absences";
                                public $name = 'Absence';
                   public $belongsTo=array('Student');`
i use this to my Student Model `public $useTable ="students";
                                public $name = 'Student';
                  public $hasMany = array('Absence');`
and i disable my code above (my question) , and still cannot works
i need u're help this error is bugging my day bro.